# swift - how to stop refreshing taps?

Tags: swift, touch, taps

I have made a bit of code that when the user taps everywhere on the screen the points/score/taps will increment by 1. But the problem is then it counts how many continuous taps I make and then if I leave a 1 second gap between pressing it will restart the counter. Is there any way I could make it stop restarting?

> CODE:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var tapsLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        let tapCount = touch.tapCount


        tapsLabel.text = "Taps: \(tapCount)"

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that makes it restart the counter after 1 second. Show us that code.

Comment: that is the only bit of code. I have added all the file

Comment: @Lamar I don't want it to refresh at all

Comment: how about `tabsLabel.text = "Taps: \(tabsLabel.text.toInt() + tapCount)"`?

Comment: @boidkan nop does not work

Comment: Oh sorry man, I am stupid I forgot about how the label has text besides the   tap count. So my solution wont work.

Comment: You could always just keep a class variable that keeps track of the count and then in touchesBegan you increment it and then update the label. Shouldn't be that hard to figure out. You could also look at apple documentation on touchesBegan and understand how it works.

Comment: @boidkan do you have the time to show me an example of that please?

Comment: and yeah that solution did not work haha :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88051/discussion-between-boidkan-and-swift101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `tapCount` documentation says:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITouch/tapCount)

> The value of this property is an integer indicating the number of times the user tapped their fingers on a certain point within a predefined period.

It's supposed to reset after some “predefined period”. You're trying to use it for something it wasn't designed for.

Instead, you need to create a property on `ViewController` to count the number of total taps:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tapCount = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var tapsLabel: UILabel!

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        tapCount += 1
        tapsLabel.text = "Taps: \(tapCount)"
    }
}
```

(Please note that my code here is for the iOS 9 API. The `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method signature is slightly different than in the iOS 8 API.)

Comment: where am I able to talk to you about something?